# How to control the Calendar App in WP 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

What app I'm trying to do without any clue is this: having a string with different properties stored inside (like location, the hours and the day for a meeting) for example:
`"New.York->12:00-14:00->Monday"`

Now, what I want to do is this: for every Monday for next 3 months to put that meeting in to my Windows Phone's Calendar app.

Please provide some help?
What should I use? Some code samples would be great or API references ...

Comment: Have you looked at the calander tasks? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207038(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, I did. What I can't figure it out is how to put on every Monday per say for next 3 mounths like in example. With tasks u can select the date but not the day. I want to select specific day. Is there a way or just hard coding after all?